# Checking for an entry in text file before adding

Tags: python

I have some fairly simple code i thought would work but it is not doing as it should, all i'm doing is reading a text file for a url, if it does not exist in the tex file we add it:

code:

```
def verify_links_working(self, url):
    if url not in open("links/register.txt").read():
        with open("links/register.txt", "a+") as file:
            file.write("%s\n" % str(url).strip())
        file.close()
```

It looks fairly straight forward but it still adds duplicate lines, is there something i have missed? any help is appreciated.

Comment: any differences between those duplicates like case(lower/upper) or trailing special char?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do both read and write on the same file, plus cleaning both url and urls from txt with strip. Since self is not used, I remove it by adding staticmethod(assuming you are using the function as a class function:

```py
@staticmethod
def verify_links_working(url):

    url_clean = url.strip()
    with open('links/register.txt', 'r+') as file:

        if url_clean not in {url.strip() for url in file}:
            file.write(f'{url_clean}\n')
```

Even better, you can pass path to register.txt as an argument instead of hard coding it in your function. In that since your function will be more generic.

Comment: Thank you Prayson i never knew that, noted :)